# How to animate Safari address bar hiding

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

The task is to hide iPhone Safari address bar on my website. 
I found the following code to solve it:

```
function hideAddressBar() { 
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTop(0, 1); }, 0); 
}

window.addEventListener('load', hideAddressBar);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', hideAddressBar);
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', hideAddressBar);
```

It works fine, but looks very ugly. 
I've tried jQuery animation, but it doesn't work because the y-offset  is not enough for animation - if bar is visible the y-offset value is 0, else it equals to 1.

I'm interesting in `slide` animation to synchronize Safari address bar showing and hiding. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could look at this code: http://iosjs.com/ and see how they do it. I use this and when the page loads, it automatically loads the page and hides the bar. It doesn't slide, as it's never shown. It's only 5K too.

Comment: It doesn't work. Try to add `input[type=text]` at the top of the page and tap on it - address bar will show. Is there way to animate hiding process?

Comment: Are you sure you are using it correctly? I am doing another responsive site right now. I just added the iOS.js file and boom, full height window, browser bar slides up after page loads.